# DataTable rowReordering issue PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

I've tried retrieve data from database table and show in DataTable, but I'm getting below error

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Could you please saw  me the error in this code ?

**PHP**

```
$displayBoxList = $this->category_m->getCategoryDisplayboxList(null, $type, $page);
$boxList = array();

foreach($displayBoxList as $key => $val)
{
    $status = ($val['isActive'] == 1) ? 'Active' : 'De-active';

    // $boxList[] = array($val['ID'],$val['heading'],$val['displayOrder'],$status);

    $boxList[$key]['ID'] = $val['ID'];
    $boxList[$key]['heading'] = $val['heading'];
    $boxList[$key]['displayOrder'] = $val['displayOrder'];
    $boxList[$key]['status'] = ($val['isActive'] == 1) ? 'Active' : 'De-active';
}

$json = json_encode($boxList);
echo $json;
```

**AJAX**

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({  

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": '<?=site_url()?>category/getDatatableData/<?=$activetab?>',
        "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex){
         $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
        }

   });

   table.rowReordering();   
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>heading</th>
         <th>displayOrder</th>
         <th>status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
         <th>heading</th>
         <th>displayOrder</th>
         <th>status</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Print your JSON and use [this](https://jsonlint.com/) to check if it's a valid format JSON

Comment: I've checked my Json, it is a valid one. thank!

Comment: You forgot the headers for your JSON: check [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: check the examples part. Draw, recordstotal, etc

Answer (score 0):

It is showing `invalid JSON response` error because you are returning only data part to datatable ajax. Php file should return data in following format:

```
$jsonData = array(
      "draw" => intval($_REQUEST['draw']),
      "recordsTotal" => 10,            // you have to get this thorugh count(*) query 
      "recordsFiltered" => 8,          // recordsFiltered will get count of records when search input is filled,
       "data" => $boxList             // This is your data in array
);

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

When data will be `echo`ed in this format, then you will not face `invalid Json response` error. jQuery datatables accept json response with `draw`, `recordsTotal`, `recordsFiltered`, `data` in json array.